# The suitable way to import data to CRM ( Smartsheet) from website?

Tags: database, wordpress, crm, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

I'm doing wordpress website. And what i wanna do is: when user send contact form ( include their information) or user register, their information is added to CRM directly.

What i wonder is :

- 1) I should write my own plugin to do these things? possible? Because I think it will get the problem of permission ( when access to CRM)
- 2) There is a contact plugin which data is saved to database. Can we do cron tab to add data every period of time?

Can I ask you guy:

- Are 2 above ways possible?
- Are there any easier and possible way to do?

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible for Smartsheet to receive such information through the Smartsheet API. To help you get started with connecting to the API with PHP, and sending data to your sheet, I recommend looking at the [Smartsheet Platform PHP Samples](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/samples/tree/master/php).

For your particular situation I would look at the [Sheet Structure sample](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/samples/tree/master/php/2-SheetStructure).